# removing the name space from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove XMLNS="http://......" from the xml. I am using the following code it is removing the XMLNS from the elements but this is also stripping the elemenet prefixes which i don't want..Please help...

Input:

```
<rss xmlns="http://www.ibm.org/wcmxml">
    <channel xmlns="">
        <title>Products WCI Feed</title>
        <link>http://www.ibm.com/feeds/sample.rss</link>
        <description>Products WCI RSS Feed</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 11:30:00 EET</lastBuildDate>
        <ibmfs:etag xmlns:ibmfs="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/feedsvc/1.0">FeedServiceServlet</ibmfs:etag>
        <item>
            <title>Product Name</title>
            <link>http://www.source-ECM-Domain.com/item/sample.htm</link>
            <description>Product Description</description>
            <pubDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 11:45:00 EET</pubDate>
            <guid>UniqieIDFromECMUpTo256Char00</guid>
            <category>/Taxonomy1/Category10/Category100</category>
            <author>author@us.ibm.com</author>
            <ibmwcm:action xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">add</ibmwcm:action>
            <ibmwcm:itemType xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">Content</ibmwcm:itemType>
            <ibmwcm:library xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">TGCS WCI Feed Service</ibmwcm:library>
            <ibmwcm:path xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">/Products</ibmwcm:path>
            <ibmwcm:displayTitle xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">ProductName</ibmwcm:displayTitle>
            <ibmwcm:authoringTemplate xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">TGCS WCI Feed Service/AT Product Info</ibmwcm:authoringTemplate>
            <ibmwcm:workflow xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0" name="WFSystem">
                <ibmwcm:workflowStage>WFStageSystemPublish</ibmwcm:workflowStage>
            </ibmwcm:workflow>
            <ibmwcm:publishDate xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">Thu, 07 Nov 2013 15:14:00 EET</ibmwcm:publishDate>
            <ibmwcm:expirationDate xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">Fri, 17 Jul 2014 11:00:00 EET</ibmwcm:expirationDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Output:

```
<rss xmlns="http://www.ibm.org/wcmxml">
    <channel xmlns="">
        <title>Products WCI Feed</title>
        <link>http://www.ibm.com/feeds/sample.rss</link>
        <description>Products WCI RSS Feed</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 11:30:00 EET</lastBuildDate>
        <etag>FeedServiceServlet</etag>
        <item>
            <title>Product Name</title>
            <link>http://www.source-ECM-Domain.com/item/sample.htm</link>
            <description>Product Description</description>
            <pubDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 11:45:00 EET</pubDate>
            <guid>UniqieIDFromECMUpTo256Char00</guid>
            <category>/Taxonomy1/Category10/Category100</category>
            <author>author@us.ibm.com</author>
            <action>add</action>
            <itemType>Content</itemType>
            <library>TGCS WCI Feed Service</library>
            <path>/Products</path>
            <displayTitle>ProductName</displayTitle>
            <authoringTemplate>TGCS WCI Feed Service/AT Product Info</authoringTemplate>
            <workflow name="WFSystem">
                <workflowStage>WFStageSystemPublish</workflowStage>
            </workflow>
            <publishDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 15:14:00 EET</publishDate>
            <expirationDate>Fri, 17 Jul 2014 11:00:00 EET</expirationDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Expecting:

```
<rss>
    <channel>
        <title>Products WCI Feed</title>
        <link>http://www.ibm.com/feeds/sample.rss</link>
        <description>Products WCI RSS Feed</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 11:30:00 EET</lastBuildDate>
        <ibmfs:etag xmlns:ibmfs="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/feedsvc/1.0">FeedServiceServlet</ibmfs:etag>
        <item>
            <title>Product Name</title>
            <link>http://www.source-ECM-Domain.com/item/sample.htm</link>
            <description>Product Description</description>
            <pubDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 11:45:00 EET</pubDate>
            <guid>UniqieIDFromECMUpTo256Char00</guid>
            <category>/Taxonomy1/Category10/Category100</category>
            <author>author@us.ibm.com</author>
            <ibmwcm:action>add</ibmwcm:action>
            <ibmwcm:itemType>Content</ibmwcm:itemType>
            <ibmwcm:library>TGCS WCI Feed Service</ibmwcm:library>
            <ibmwcm:path>/Products</ibmwcm:path>
            <ibmwcm:displayTitle>ProductName</ibmwcm:displayTitle>
            <ibmwcm:authoringTemplate>TGCS WCI Feed Service/AT Product Info</ibmwcm:authoringTemplate>
            <ibmwcm:workflow name="WFSystem">
                <ibmwcm:workflowStage>WFStageSystemPublish</ibmwcm:workflowStage>
            </ibmwcm:workflow>
            <ibmwcm:publishDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 15:14:00 EET</ibmwcm:publishDate>
            <ibmwcm:expirationDate>Fri, 17 Jul 2014 11:00:00 EET</ibmwcm:expirationDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

XLST used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove element prefix -->
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <!-- process attributes -->
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <!-- remove attribute prefix -->
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help i want no XMLNS in the XML at all..

Thanks,
Srini

Comment: The output that you expect is not valid XML because the prefix "ibmwcm" is not bound to a namespace. I suggest you revise your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid the `xmlns:ibmwcm` entirely, because without it your elements with `ibmwcm` prefixed names are not namespace-well-formed.  But you could move the declaration up to a higher level rather than having it repeated on every sub-element that uses the prefix.

Apart from that, the only semantic difference between your input and expected output documents is that in the input the root-level element is `rss` in the `http://www.ibm.org/wcmxml` namespace and in your expected output it is `rss` in *no* namespace.  So the following should be sufficient:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <rss xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
    </rss>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following output:

```
<rss xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Products WCI Feed</title>
        <link>http://www.ibm.com/feeds/sample.rss</link>
        <description>Products WCI RSS Feed</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 11:30:00 EET</lastBuildDate>
        <ibmfs:etag xmlns:ibmfs="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/feedsvc/1.0">FeedServiceServlet</ibmfs:etag>
        <item>
            <title>Product Name</title>
            <link>http://www.source-ECM-Domain.com/item/sample.htm</link>
            <description>Product Description</description>
            <pubDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 11:45:00 EET</pubDate>
            <guid>UniqieIDFromECMUpTo256Char00</guid>
            <category>/Taxonomy1/Category10/Category100</category>
            <author>author@us.ibm.com</author>
            <ibmwcm:action>add</ibmwcm:action>
            <ibmwcm:itemType>Content</ibmwcm:itemType>
            <ibmwcm:library>TGCS WCI Feed Service</ibmwcm:library>
            <ibmwcm:path>/Products</ibmwcm:path>
            <ibmwcm:displayTitle>ProductName</ibmwcm:displayTitle>
            <ibmwcm:authoringTemplate>TGCS WCI Feed Service/AT Product Info</ibmwcm:authoringTemplate>
            <ibmwcm:workflow name="WFSystem">
                <ibmwcm:workflowStage>WFStageSystemPublish</ibmwcm:workflowStage>
            </ibmwcm:workflow>
            <ibmwcm:publishDate>Thu, 07 Nov 2013 15:14:00 EET</ibmwcm:publishDate>
            <ibmwcm:expirationDate>Fri, 17 Jul 2014 11:00:00 EET</ibmwcm:expirationDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

with all the repeated declarations of the same namespace removed, and the `xmlns` declarations on `rss` and `channel` removed too.

Comment: This helped me resolve the issue..Thank you very much for you inputs.

Comment: @user3158356, Please accept the answer that was most helpful to you (mark the tick on the left). In my opinion, this is Ian's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you would like to strip your XML of any namespace while retaining the prefixes like `ibmwcm:`.

This not possible and it does not make sense, either.

Let's clear up the issue a bit. Look at the following namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0"
```

This instruction does the following: it declares `http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0` as a namespace in your XML file and also tells you that `ibmwcm` is used as its prefix. The prefix is just a shorter way of writing the whole namespace. So,

```
<ibmwcm:workflow/>
```

actually means the same as:

```
<workflow xmlns="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0"/>
```

Now, you see why it does not make sense to separate the prefix from its namespace I hope, since both denote the same.

Yet, there is room for actual improvement in your XML. You cannot remove the namespace declaration entirely from your XML, but you can declare it on the document node (root node) like this:

```
<rss xmlns:ibmwcm="http://purl.org/net/ibmfeedsvc/wcm/1.0"/>
```

And later refer to it only as:

```
<ibmwcm:workflow/>
```

That way, you don't have to repeat the namespace many times over, as in your input XML.

Comment: I am new to XSLT and have this issue. Thanks for your valuable inputs on this.

Answer (score -2):

You don't want to remove the XMLNS.  The XML will not work without it.  It gives the namespace which disambiguates the element names.  You can remove the XSL: previx by making the namespace the default like this

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

This is a good place to read about namespaces

[W3Schools Namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

Comment: The `xsl:` prefix does not need to be removed. Also, this is considered extremely bad practice - together with W3Schools, which is an extremely unreliable resource for learning.

Comment: There is no `xsl:` prefix in the output - so it's not necessary to remove it.